# How do you detect a change from localhost/foo to localhost/baa?

Tags: javascript, routes

How do you detect a change from localhost/foo to localhost/baa events location change and pushstate listeners don't work?

The path is being changed internally by a routing lib.

```
// update doesn't get called
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', update);
    window.addEventListener('pushstate', update);
    window.addEventListener('onpopstate', update);
```

the only otherway to do this is to manually dispatch events (to the body) to let the `update` function know to run

Comment: I don’t think pop state event has “on” at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
function doSomehting(newURL) {
    console.log('yep');
}

window.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
  var lastURL = localStorage.getItem('lastURL');
  var newURL = location.href;
  (lastURL && decodeURI(lastURL) != newURL) && doSomehting(newURL);
  localStorage.setItem('lastURL', encodeURI(newURL));
});
```

You should load this script on every page you would like to receive events from.